# I get error 1053 at end of my C# service. How do I stop it?

Tags: c#, rest, restsharp, filemaker

I'm trying to make a service on a server that runs every 24 hours to get information from Blancco reports, then input it into a Filemaker database.

The service works completely as it should but every time it ends, I get the meesage box error:
`Error 1053: the service did not respond to the start or control request in a timely fashion`

I tried to run service on my pc and I don't get any errors there. So I guess there might be something wrong with the server, but I don't know what.
Hopefully one of you guys know

code:

```
using System;
using System.ServiceProcess;

namespace Blancco_Report_Service
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Service service = new Service();
            
            if (Environment.UserInteractive)
            {
                service.RunAsConsole(args);
            }
            else
            {
                ServiceBase[] services;
                services = new ServiceBase[] { service };
                ServiceBase.Run(services);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I know it looks weird I made it create a batch file to get the reports, but I could not get Blancco's API to work with RestSharp so this was the next best option. This is not important anyways

```
using Newtonsoft.Json;
using Newtonsoft.Json.Linq;
using RestSharp;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Configuration;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.IO;
using System.ServiceProcess;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading;
using System.Xml;
using Formatting = Newtonsoft.Json.Formatting;

namespace Blancco_Report_Service
{
    class Service : ServiceBase
    {
        private string fmToken = "placeholder";
        Thread work;

        public void RunAsConsole(string[] args)
        {
            OnStart(args);
            Console.ReadLine();
            OnStop();
        }

        protected override void OnStart(string[] args)
        {
            work = new Thread(new ThreadStart(Work));
            work.Start();
        }

        protected override void OnStop()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Stopping");
            try
            {
                work.Abort();
            }
            catch (Exception)
            {

            }

        }

        private void Work()
        {
            List<Report> reports = GetReports();
            foreach (var report in reports)
            {
                UpdateField(report);
            }
        }

        private List<Report> GetReports()
        {
            List<Report> reports = new List<Report>();
            StringBuilder output = new StringBuilder();
            XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
            Process process = new Process();

            Console.WriteLine(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory + "export.bat");
            ProcessStartInfo startInfo = new ProcessStartInfo("cmd.exe", "/C \"" + AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory + "export.bat\"");
            startInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
            startInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
            process.StartInfo = startInfo;
            process.OutputDataReceived += (sender, args) => output.Append(args.Data);
            process.Start();
            process.BeginOutputReadLine();
            process.WaitForExit();

            string[] outputSplit = output.ToString().Split("web-service-request.xml\" ");
            try
            {
                doc.LoadXml(outputSplit[1]);
            }
            catch (Exception)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("No reports");
                return reports;
            }
            string json = JsonConvert.SerializeXmlNode(doc, Formatting.None, true);
            json = json.Substring(45);
            dynamic result = JObject.Parse(json);

            foreach (var report in result.report)
            {
                Report reportClass = new Report();
                try
                {
                    dynamic blancco_data = report.blancco_data;
                    dynamic blancco_hardware_report = blancco_data.blancco_hardware_report;
                    dynamic hardware_entries = blancco_hardware_report.entries;

                    foreach (var hardwere_entry in hardware_entries)
                    {
                        if (hardwere_entry["@name"] == "system")
                        {
                            dynamic system_entry = hardwere_entry.entry;

                            foreach (var systemInfo in system_entry)
                            {
                                if (systemInfo["@name"] == "serial")
                                {
                                    reportClass.Serial = systemInfo["#text"];
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }

                    dynamic description = blancco_data.description;
                    dynamic document_log = description.document_log;
                    dynamic log_entry = document_log.log_entry[0];
                    string date = log_entry.date;
                    DateTime oDate = DateTime.ParseExact(date, "MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss", System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
                    date = oDate.ToString();

                    reportClass.Date = date;

                    reports.Add(reportClass);
                }
                catch (Exception e)
                {

                }
            }
            return reports;
        }

        private void UpdateField(Report report)
        {
            var client = new RestClient(FMAPI.Url + "_find");
            var request = new RestRequest(Method.POST);
            request.AddHeader("cache-control", "no-cache");
            request.AddHeader("authorization", "Bearer " + fmToken);
            request.AddHeader("content-type", "application/json");
            request.AddParameter("application/json", "{ \"query\": [{ \"service::ser_serial no\": \"=" + report.Serial + "\"}] }", ParameterType.RequestBody);
            IRestResponse response = client.Execute(request);

            dynamic result = JObject.Parse(response.Content);
            string code = result.messages[0].code;

            switch (code)
            {
                case "952":
                    fmToken = FMAPI.GetToken("service_000_DK");
                    UpdateField(report);
                    return;
                case "401": return;
                default: break;
            }

            string recordID = result.response.data[0].recordId;

            client = new RestClient(FMAPI.Url + "records/" + recordID);
            request = new RestRequest(Method.PATCH);
            request.AddHeader("cache-control", "no-cache");
            request.AddHeader("content-type", "application/json");
            request.AddHeader("authorization", "Bearer " + fmToken);
            request.AddParameter("application/json", "{ \"fieldData\": { \"service::ser_dataerased\": \"" + report.Date + "\" } }", ParameterType.RequestBody);
            response = client.Execute(request);

            result = JObject.Parse(response.Content);
            code = result.messages[0].code;

            if (code == "0")
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Uploaded");
            }
            else
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Failed to Upload");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: `work.Abort();` ... :( WHY?? Why is this a windows service _at all_? You could have a Console App executed by Windows Task Scheduler. Much simpler.

Comment: @Fildor maybe task scheduler would have seen more usage if it had been more intuitive to use...

Comment: @mortb That's just lazy. But maybe it would be used more often if people actually knew what their systems come with out of the box.